# How to fix " 'nf' is not recognized as an internal or external command"?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm following this tutorial for making react electron apps in this URL:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-an-electron-application-with-create-react-app-97945861647c/

Everything worked fine initially until I installed react-bootstrap which got me this error

**'nf' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

I've since then uninstalled react-bootstrap but the problem still persists.

Here's a list of what I've done but are unsuccessful:

1. Deleted the package-lock then reinstalled the project.
2. Installed nf then uninstalled.

Currently, Here's what my package.json contains:

```
{
  "name": "uav",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "main": "src/electron-starter.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-dev": "set ELECTRON_START_URL=http://localhost:3000 && electron .",
    "dev": "nf start"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.1"
  }
}
```

I also looked for issues similar to mine in SO but none resolved my issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

- npm install
- npm rebuild node-sass
- then run the command `npm run dev` again since it triggers the `nf start`